# Source nat in netfilter prerouting hooks

Tags: linux-kernel, nat, kernel-module, netfilter

We are developing our own kernel module that does advanced source nat in netfilter prerouting hook. After upgrading from Linux kernel 2.6.32 (Ubuntu 10.04) to 2.6.35 (Ubuntu 10.04 lucid-back-ports) it seems that SNATted packets are simply dropped inside the Linux kernel.

I know that SNAT was never advised to be done in Prerouting hooks for general usage ([Netfilter mailing list](http://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter/2001-May/010686.html)), but there are still some reasons why we would prefer to do source natting before the actual routing decision is made.

**Has anyone experience of developing kernel modules that do SNAT in netfilter prerouting hook for 2.6.35+ linux kernel? What exactly should be changed in linux-kernel/netfilter-kernel-module code so that SNATted packets would not be dropped? Maybe SNAT in prerouting is simply a bad idea for 2.6.35+ Linux kernel and we should better use nf_marks for routing decision and do the SNAT in postrouting?**

I am using Ubunut 10.04 with back-ported Linux kernel (2.6.35) on X86_64.

Answer (score 0):

Start with finding exact line which drops the packet.

Comment: Do you have any experience with SNAT in prerouting? Maybe there is an easier solutions than looking into source code and "fixing" this myself (e.g. maybe there is already a patch roaming for this somewhere; or maybe this can be done with /sys filesystem). Linux code base is very big, and I know that I would not be able to analyze all possible regressions in just one week after "fixing" this myself. That is also the reason why I asked for expert help who might already have solved similar issue before. Anyway thanks for advice :)

Comment: It is big, but arbitrary line can't make a packet disappear. You're looking for at least `kfree_skb()` calls. The point you don't know what's going on, and your out-of-treeness of a module does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you re-calculated all checksums after updating the source IP? Keep in mind that you will also need to update TCP/UDP checksums as they are based on the src/dst IP address.